# Bootstrap-select CDN isn't loading on Django template which contains a bootstrap modal

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Django project which contains a bunch of CDNs which provide various front end features in my templates.

One CDN in particular, Bootstrap-Select, refuses to load in my template which provides a bootstrap modal. I know CDNs are communicating to my bootstrap modal, because the modal is bootstrap and bootstrap it's self is obviously contained from a CDN.

I also know the CDN itself works because I can use it within my index files

I'm not quite sure what code to provide, so I'll provide a few things

This is the li tag and responding div which contains defaults for my template inside my index.html

```
<li class="edit_exceptions"><a href="/awd_role_tool/edit_exceptions" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Exceptions</a></li>
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                          <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                              <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
                              <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
                              <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
                            </select>

                        <h6>Table is loading...</h6>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

This is the template which will not load the CDN. I've tried including the CDN inside the template, inside my HTML, I've tried including a local download of the CDN - none of this works.

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">AWD Exception Table</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>

        <div id="dropDownExceptions">
            <div id="titleCont">
            <div class="listTitle">Select employee</div><div class="listTitle">Select a Role</div>
                </div>
            <div id="selectCont">
            <select class="form-control">

                {% for people in employees %}
                <option value={{people.name}}>{{people.name}}</option>
                <!--<li>{{people.role}}</li>-->
                {% endfor %}

            </select>
            <select class="form-control">


                {% for people in employees %}
                <!--<li>{{people.name}}</li>-->
                <option value={{people.role}}>{{people.role}}</option>

                {% endfor %}

            </select>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" onClick="edit_exception()" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" onClick="delete_exception()" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The < select class="selectpicker ... > tag is the syntax for the select menu CDN which won't load inside my modal - but it loads just fine inside my index.

Please let me know if you'd like to see any other code or if anything I've said is unclear. This problem is rather annoying because it's difficult to describe and I'm not sure why I'm having so much difficulty getting this to work.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example)!